# Set textBlock foreground based on the weekday in its Text property purely in XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a textBlock which contains a date in the text property.
Now, I would like to set the foreground color of that textBlock based on the day of week in it's text property.

Can that be done purely in XAML?

Thanks

Comment: You need to write a converter, I think, to convert the day of the week into a colour.

Comment: You need to edit your Question with that information.

Answer (score 2):

Not in pure `XAML`, you need to create a class that implements `IValueConverter`, then by referencing it in your `XAML` you can bind the `TextBlock` color to the date property which will transform into a `Brush` via the converter.

For more information on `ValueConverter` look here:

https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/868163/%2FTips%2F868163%2FIValueConverter-Example-and-Usage-in-WPF

Comment: Ok, thanks, good to know. Looks like the solution with `IValueConverter` would be the way to go. Seems like the proper solution anyway to handle convertions according to the MVVM philosophy, is that right? I'm pretty new to programming C# and all the MVVM stuff!!

Answer (score 1):

> Now, I would like to set the foreground color of that textBlock based on the day of week in it's text property

Pure xaml:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="Text" Value="Monday"><!-- You will need to do this for every day of the week-->
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Green"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Also if you break down the date using `Runs` then you can assign a style to a run, like this:

```
<TextBlock>
    <Run Text="{Binding Today}"/>
    <Run Text="{Binding Today.DayOfWeek, Mode=OneWay}"/><!-- This has to be one way as the Property DayOfWeek is readonly -->
</TextBlock>
```

And then in resources use this:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Run}">
    <Style.Triggers>
       <Trigger Property="Text" Value="Friday">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Green"/>
       </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Comment: This doesn't work, since the text contained looks like this: "Freitag, 4. Januar 2019". Unless, there's like a "contains" command or something? I was thinking of a solution similar to `DayOfWeek`in code, but  didn't find anything. Otherwise I will try to do it via a converter, seems to be a good thing to master anyway.

Comment: Thought you might say that, that's why I added the "Run" alternative. If you break it down into runs, then the style will work. But this is an alternative, if you want to keep it pure xaml, like you asked.

Comment: Thanks! I have to get my head around that "run" thing and try it out, but it sounds promissing!!

Comment: You need to put the style in the top element or Resources tag not the actual TextBlock

Comment: Never got that one to work, but I solved it with a converter now.